# Turn Parts of Rows into a Separate Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure if Pivot is the way to go with this, but I am looking to take part of a row and create a new column with it.

This is my example:

```
+--------+------------+--------+
| Person |  PetName   | PetAge |
+--------+------------+--------+
|      1 | Apple      |      2 |
|      1 | Banana     |      6 |
|      1 | Grapefruit |      3 |
|      2 | Red        |     53 |
|      2 | Blue       |      8 |
+--------+------------+--------+
```

This is my result/goal:

```
+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------+
| Person | PetName | PetAge | PetName | PetAge |  PetName   | PetAge |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------+
|      1 | Apple   |      2 | Banana  |      6 | Grapefruit |      3 |
|      2 | Red     |     53 | Blue    |      8 |            |        |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------+
```

How can I get the result from my example?

Comment: How do you decide the ordering in the columns?  Is there a limit on how many columns?  This is more than a simple pivot.

Comment: The limit on the number of columns would be the maximum number of pets per person. So if someone has 21 pets, the number of PetName/PetAge columns would be 21, for a total of 43 columns.

Comment: I think you'd have to use loops and dynamic sql in that case.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I just noticed that your table just had the Person in the first row.

I've done something similar. What I did was add a **RowNumber** per pet by person (OVER PARTITION BY PERSON) to the data. This will allow the data to be broken up and an order of numbers for each pet per person.

Make your normal table with just the PetName and PetAge.

Add a Tablix with just one column and row and put the previous table in it.

For the Column grouping, use ROW_NUM. For Row use Person.

[image]

Comment: This is not T-SQL example, in reporting services is possible, but in T-SQL, Cursor would help

Comment: Duh - sorry. I thought it was SSRS for some reason.